# Why does Scala's foreach not use camelCase

Tags: scala

I'm just starting to have a play around with Scala, and according to the [style guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html) it adopts camelCase for method names.

So my question is why is the `foreach` method not called `forEach`?

Comment: I think it's for historical reasons. The `foreach` keyword is popular in other languages so I guess they adopted it.

Comment: And `forall`. And why is the keyword `forSome`; I guess so you don't think `foursome` and swinging couples. `java.lang.Runtime` but `runtime.ScalaRunTime`. etc.

Comment: There are rarely gratifying answers to this sort of question…

Comment: I personally really like questions like this, especially when they have answers, but Stack Overflow isn't the right place for them.

Comment: @TravisBrown where would be a more appropriate place for it?